# WCF: Best way to send binary data for IIS-hosted services

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-6

I have WCF service that is IIS-hosted and I have to send binary data (memory stream that is created by service) in intranet environment.
I use `byte[] array`  in service contract method at present with httpBinding. Though array is not too big (500 KB typically) I am worried about unicode overhead (asmx soap web-services had one, but I'm new to WCF).

What is the best practice to pass binary data with http binding? Can I use tcp/ip for IIS hosted WCF services?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you [MTOM](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/05/14/using-mtom-with-wcf.aspx) encoding in this case. And [here's another example](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2009/01/wcf-with-mtom-message-encoding.html). Starting from IIS7 you can use `netTcpxxx` binary bindings but not in IIS6.